# how to get the response xml from request xml in wcf soap web service in android

Tags: android, xml, wcf, soap

Below is my request xml which i want to send to wcf service with basichttpbinding. Please help me to execute this request and get the response.

Is there any other way to get the response result with same request.

**Request XML :-**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ISiplService/GetXMLForOrders</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetXMLForOrders xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <orderList xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <pOrdersList xmlns="">
          <Order>
            <Address>sd 321</Address>
            <CityName>hosiyarpur</CityName>
            <CreatedOn>2013-08-29T11:25:00</CreatedOn>
            <DeliveryCharges>0</DeliveryCharges>
            <EMail>ramandeep@test.com</EMail>
            <FirstName>ramn</FirstName>
            <LastName>deep</LastName>
            <Mobile>9999999999</Mobile>
            <ModeOfPayment>COD</ModeOfPayment>
            <OrderDetailsList>
              <OrderDetails>
                <CampaignId>11799</CampaignId>
                <OrderDetailId>11799</OrderDetailId>
                <Price>399</Price>
                <Qty>1</Qty>
                <SkuIds>1270</SkuIds>
                <SkuSizeIds>0</SkuSizeIds>
              </OrderDetails>
            </OrderDetailsList>
            <OrderId>11799</OrderId>
            <Phone>9999999999</Phone>
            <PinCode>123456</PinCode>
            <PromoCode i:nil="true" />
            <PromoSiteId>23</PromoSiteId>
            <PurchaseFrom>Hello</PurchaseFrom>
            <ShoppingPoints>0</ShoppingPoints>
            <SourceSite>Hello.com</SourceSite>
            <Status>ordered</Status>
            <TotalPrice>399</TotalPrice>
            <VerifiedOn>2013-08-29T11:25:00</VerifiedOn>
          </Order>
        </pOrdersList>
      </orderList>
    </GetXMLForOrders>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Is there any url for the xml and what are the detail you need get from the xml...

Comment: I just need a code for getting the response for this requested XML in WCF service and yes there is a URL with it u can just leave that to me just priovide with the code to send the request and get the response XML